# Form Validation Undefined or null reference of 'replace'

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to validate a simple form with the following code and I keep getting the following error: Error: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference.   What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
var test = function(){
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
            var t = e[i].getAttribute("type");
            var n = e[i].tagName;
            var v = e[i].value.replace(" ", "");
            if (v === "" && (n === "input" && (t === "text" || t === "tel" || t === "email") || n === "select")){
                alert("Please Fill Out All Fields");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="test();">
<div style="padding-left:50px; padding-top:50px;">
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
> var e = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

will return a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) that is every element in the document. Not every element has a value property, so when you do:

```
> var v = e[i].value.replace(" ", "");
```

you are treating an undefined property as a string, which it isn't.

To validate form controls, use something like:

```
var elements = document.forms['form1'].elements;
```

so that [*elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements) contains only the controls in the form *form1*.